# Composition of continuous fonctions VS Limit of composite functions

Tags: limits, function-and-relation-composition

We know that the composition of continuous fonctions is continuous, but we don't have an analogous property for the limit of composite functions. Is there anyone that could explicitly explain why this is not true in general? I have already found a counterexample, but I can't explain why this property is not true in general.

Comment: Please see [my blog post](https://vincenttam.github.io/blog/2014/11/08/composition-of-limits/) about the general reason.

Comment: @GNUSupporter I think this question is worth to be answered on this website. There could be other curious wanting to have an answer in the future.